# How to convert ParallelIterator back to sequential Iterator?

Tags: rust, rayon

I'm iterating over several gigabytes of input items from a database. On each input item, I'm doing some CPU-intensive processing which produces one or more new output items, tens of gigabytes in total. The output items are then stored in another database table.

I have gotten a nice speedup by using Rayon for parallel processing. However, the database API is not thread-safe; it's `Send` but not `Sync`, so the I/O must be serialized.

Ideally, I would just want to write:

```rust
input_database
    .read_items()
    .par_bridge() // Start parallelism.
    .flat_map_iter(|input_item| {
        // produce an Iterator<Item = OutputItem>
    })
    .ser_bridge() // End parallelism. This function does not exist.
    .for_each(|output_item| {
        output_database.write_item(output_item);
    });
```

Basically I want the opposite of `par_bridge()`; something that runs on the thread where it's called, reads items from each thread, and produces them serially. But in the current implementation of Rayon, this doesn't seem to exist. I'm not sure whether this is because it's theoretically impossible, or whether it doesn't fit into the current design of the library.

The output is too big to collect it all into a `Vec` first; it needs to be streamed into the database directly.

By the way, I'm not married to Rayon; if there's another crate that is more suitable, I'm happy to make the switch.

Comment: See also the discussion on the Rayon issue tracker about this use case: https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the order doesn't matter, therefore you don't need to have an order of your output data.

You could use a [`mpsc::channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) to transfer your data from the `for_each` closure to your database api, e.g.

```
use std::sync::mpsc;

let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

input_database
    .read_items()
    .par_bridge() // Start parallelism.
    .flat_map_iter(|input_item| {
        // produce an Iterator<Item = OutputItem>
    })
    .for_each(move |output_item| {
        tx.send(output_item).unwrap();
    });
```

and in a second thread you can use the `rx` variable to receive the data and write it to the database.

Comment: True, order doesn't matter in my case. I ended up with something similar except using a `crossbeam::channel`.

Comment: crossbeam has better performance, indeed. I used std for simplicity reasons.

Comment: @Thomas You are probably aware of that, but just in case: if you use channels, consider using a bounded channel to provide backpressure and avoid a memory leak when the channel consumer is slower than the producer.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your output database in an `Arc<Mutex>` to prevent parallel accesses:

```
let output_database = Arc::new (Mutex::new (output_database));
input_database
    .read_items()
    .par_bridge() // Start parallelism.
    .flat_map_iter(|input_item| {
        // produce an Iterator<Item = OutputItem>
    })
    .for_each_with (output_database, |output_database, output_item| {
        output_database.lock().write_item(output_item);
    });
```